# (JavaFX) How can I change a picture in an ImageView thats coded in an fxml file with a basic java class?

Tags: java, button, javafx, imageview, fxml

I am currently making a program, I want to have a button get clicked and it runs another class and depending on the output of that class, I want an image view on the same scene as the button that was clicked to be changed. I have everything coded up to the point where the output changes the image. How can I go about doing this?

Java Class

```
public static void USPSCase() {
        printUSPS();
    }

    public static void printUSPS(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int gunSelect = rand.nextInt(99)+1;

        if(gunSelect<=30){ //Calculates which gun you will get
            LeadConduitUSPS(CaseSpinners.USPSCaseSpinController.setUSPImage);
        }
        else if(gunSelect>=31 && gunSelect<=60){
            NightOpsUSPS();
        }
        else if(gunSelect>=61 && gunSelect<=90){
            TorqueUSPS();
        }
        else if(gunSelect>=91 && gunSelect<=93.5){
            GuardianUSPS();
        }
        else if(gunSelect>=94.5 && gunSelect<=97){
            CyrexUSPS();
        }
        else if(gunSelect>=98 && gunSelect<=99){
            CaimanUSPS();
        }
        else if(gunSelect==100){
            KillConfirmedUSPS();
        }


    }

//some code... these two methods are connected
                    public static void LeadConduitUSPS(ImageView setUSPImage){
        System.out.println("Lead Conduit");

        Random rand = new Random();
        int wareSelect = rand.nextInt(99)+1;

if(wareSelect<=10){ //Calculates the ware the gun has
            setUSPImage.setImage(new Image("csgocaseopener/icon.png"));
        }
        else if(wareSelect>=11 && wareSelect<=25){
            setUSPImage.setImage(new Image("csgocaseopener/icon.png"));
        }
        else if(wareSelect>=26 && wareSelect<=60){
            setUSPImage.setImage(new Image("csgocaseopener/icon.png"));
        }
        else if(wareSelect>=61 && wareSelect<=80){
            setUSPImage.setImage(new Image("csgocaseopener/icon.png"));
        }
        else if(wareSelect>=81){
            setUSPImage.setImage(new Image("csgocaseopener/icon.png"));
        }
    }
```

fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="CaseSpinners.USPSCaseSpinController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../csgocaseopener/back.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="spinmechback" fitHeight="45.0" fitWidth="45.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSpinMechBack" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="-1.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../csgocaseopener/backbtn.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button fx:id="SpinUSPS" layoutX="235.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SpinUSPSCase" text="SPIN">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <ImageView fx:id="setAWPImage" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="100.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../csgocaseopener/bprof.png" />
         </image></ImageView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

fxml controller

```
public class USPSCaseSpinController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        public static ImageView setUSPImage;

        @FXML
        private void handleSpinMechBack(MouseEvent event) throws IOException{
        Parent handleInventoryBackParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/csgocaseopener/OpenCase.fxml"));
        Scene OPBackScene = new Scene(handleInventoryBackParent);
        Stage handleInventoryBackStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        handleInventoryBackStage.setScene(OPBackScene);
        handleInventoryBackStage.show();
        }

        @FXML
        private void SpinUSPSCase(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
            test test = new test();
            test.LeadConduitUSPS(setUSPImage);
        }
        @FXML
        public void SetUSPImage(){
            setUSPImage.setImage(new Image("AWPCase.png"));
        }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you share your sample codes?

Comment: Just added the java class, fxml, and fxml controller

Comment: If you need more of the Java class let me know

Comment: You can set the imageview which to be changed to related class constructor or its method parameter later you can change it. For example your method may be "LeadConduitUSPS(Imageview img)". Main point you should obtain controller imageview instance in related class.

Comment: So if I did that would each of statement be able to change the image view to a different image, I also apologize if I'm doing something wrong, I'm fairly new to this site (programming as well)

Comment: When you said (imageview img), would img be equal to the fxid of the image view or an image URL?

Comment: It must be instance of fxml imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make parameterized method for `LeadConduitUSPS()` in your supporter class. Like this,

```
public static void LeadConduitUSPS(ImageView image){
    System.out.println("Lead Conduit");

    Random rand = new Random();
    int wareSelect = ((int)(rand.nextDouble() * 99)) +1;

    if(wareSelect<=10){ //Calculates the ware the gun has
        System.out.println("Factory New");
    }
    else if(wareSelect>=11 && wareSelect<=25){
        //Changes Image here!!
        image.setImage(new Image("new_image1.png");
    }
    else if(wareSelect>=26 && wareSelect<=60){
        //Changes Image here!!
        image.setImage(new Image("new_image2.png");
    }
    else if(wareSelect>=61 && wareSelect<=80){
        //Changes Image here!!
        image.setImage(new Image("new_image3.png");
    }
    else if(wareSelect>=81){
        //Changes Image here!!
        image.setImage(new Image("new_image4.png");
    }
}
```

Then call `LeadConduitUSPS()` method from the Controller class's `SpinUSPSCase()`,

```
public class USPSCaseSpinController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ImageView setUSPImage;

    @FXML
    private void handleSpinMechBack(MouseEvent event) throws IOException{
    Parent handleInventoryBackParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/csgocaseopener/OpenCase.fxml"));
    Scene OPBackScene = new Scene(handleInventoryBackParent);
    Stage handleInventoryBackStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    handleInventoryBackStage.setScene(OPBackScene);
    handleInventoryBackStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void SpinUSPSCase(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        //call from here
        YourAnotherClass test = new YourAnotherClass();
        test.LeadConduitUSPS(USPImage);
    }

    @FXML
    public void SetUSPImage(){
        setUSPImage.setImage(new Image("AWPCase.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi again! This program is now just about working flawlessly, I was just wondering if there was anyway I could pass multiple parameters to the LeadConduit method? It gets called in a different part of the test class and it's outputing an error because it can pass what it's calling with the method just having the image view parameter.

Comment: everything is just about running perfectly but the only problem I have now is im getting a NullPointerException error, any ideas?

Comment: Where you are getting the `NullPointerException`? For 
       image.setImage(new Image()) or somewhere else?

Comment: its randomly alternating between the codethat is within the if and if else statements in the test.java class which is a good thing because that means that the code before it is working, but it also occurs at the test.LeadConduit(setUSPImage) line in the controller class

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at csgocaseopener.test.LeadConduitUSPS(test.java:224)
 at CaseSpinners.USPSCaseSpinController.SpinUSPSCase(USPSCaseSpinController.java:46)

Comment: What is the code in the line of 224? I think it's all about the ImageView object.

Comment: setUSPImage.setImage(new Image("csgocaseopener/icon.png"));     this is the line, each time i run it, the program alternates between these in the if statements but that is a good thing as previously mentioned, thank you so much for helping by the way!

Comment: Feel free to ask, but i'm confused that why your code mentioned in the comment is different than your question's code? -> setUSPImage and USPImage? Please update the question. And it seems that the your ImageView throwing the NullPointerException.

Comment: Sorry they're the same thing, I just changed the fxid

Comment: Check whether the @FXML private ImageView `USPImage`; is equivalent to your ImageView `FXID` or not.

Comment: You've found the error, it was the fact that he fxid was accidentally changed,  it works now. thank you for everything!

Comment: Okay, I apologize for the fact that I keep bothering you, so sorry! this works flawlessly with no errors, the only thing I was wondering was the test.java class basically randomly selects one of seven possible methods(you can see this in the updated code), and then after that it goes through those five if statements in the method it chooses. but now when the method is called, it only puts out the first possible method because its called in the controller class, is there any way i can make it get the method it randomly chose in the controller class?

Comment: Update your code `int wareSelect = ((int)(rand.nextDouble() * 99)) +1;` instead of `int wareSelect = rand.nextInt(99)+1;`.

Comment: okay, could I have the class method get the random number from the weapon select method and then have some extra code in the controller to call the proper method?

Comment: I guess there is no need of controller method, check and run the code first. I also updated the answer.

Comment: yea it just always uses the same method because when you call test.LeadConduitUSP(setUSPImage) it is always using the LeadConduit method, I need to find a way to get it to know which method the printUSPS gives us

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the ImageView instance (USPImage) which provided from FXML to your `LeadConduitUSPS(ImageView imgView)` method. Then you can set an Image to this `imgView` in your related class. Hope it is useful.

Comment: everything seems to be working well with this code but I seem to be getting a NullPointerException toward the end of the code, have any ideas as to why?

Comment: @Tresk33, Can you check fxml 'USPImage' ImageView before set 'LeadConduitUSPS(USPImage)' ? It may be null.